# Fast way to match anchored regex in the middle of the string

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Consider such code:

```
Match match = new Regex("^bar").Match(some_string,3);
```

I would like to match `some_string` but not from the beginning of it, but starting from given position. The catch is, I would like to make a match **exactly** from that position, thus the anchor.

Unfortunately, it does not work. MS regex does not work with chunks of the string as strings on their own, so `^` matches only the one and true beginning of the **string** not of **starting position**.

The easy workaround is to write this in such way:

```
Match match = new Regex("^bar").Match(some_string.Substring(3));
```

The downsize -- **speed** (i.e. lack of it).

So my question is this -- how to match anchored regex in the middle of the string, **fast**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

.NET has a separate anchor for the position where the engine starts (usually the end of the last match, in your case the offset): `\G`.

So you should be able to use the pattern `@"\Gbar"`.

[Source (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3583dcyh.aspx)

> If you want to restrict a match so that it begins at a particular character position in the string and the regular expression engine does not scan the remainder of the string for a match, anchor the regular expression with a `\G` (at the left for a left-to-right pattern, or at the right for a right-to-left pattern). This restricts the match so it must start exactly at `startat`.

Comment: Awesome! I have to wait 10 minutes to accept your answer, though, sorry, SO issues...